# My question deleted?

Tags: support

I posted a question regarding my trouble at home where I said my mother is hurting and punishing me for an unjust reason and I asked how should I solve the situation. Now I am unable to find the question, as it got deleted. Why would it get deleted? I didn't get to read all the answers.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this site (like all Internet sites) cannot be a stand in for professional support in cases like this. So while we can be sympathetic, we don't have the capability to assist.

Accordingly, the question is closed and referred to CM's for potential referral to more useful avenues.

Comment: Well it was a question that questioned whether professional support is necessary.

Comment: Sorry, no. What it was asking for was how to solve your situation. As I said, that is off topic here.